# Hasql Session's return value variable getting stuck with specific type?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, hasql

I am attempting to connect to Postgres once, outside of my Spock application, but I can't seem to use a Hasql session handle with multiple return types.

My main application is fairly straightforward, but fails to compile.

```
mainApp :: IO Middleware
mainApp = do
  session pgConfig sessConfig $ do
    dbHandle <- sessionUnlifter
    liftIO $ do
      printAHasqlString dbHandle
      printAccountCount dbHandle
      spockT id (appMiddleware >> appRoutes dbHandle)
```

If I comment out `printAHasqlString` or `printAccountCount`, it compiles and works (both work when running without the other).

```
printAccountCount :: (MonadBase IO m) => (Session Settings s m Int -> IO Int) -> IO ()
printAHasqlString :: (MonadBase IO m) => (Session Settings s m Text -> IO Text) -> IO ()
```

`printAccountCount` does a query returning an Int, and `printAHasqlString` runs a query for a Text.  Both just print the result, and returns an `IO ()`.

But when I attempt to run both queries in the same application, the `r` type variable in the `Session` data type gets locked down, and fails to compile with the second one.

**Error Message:**

```
src/Main.hs:30:25:
  Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Int’
  Expected type: Session Settings s IO Int -> IO Int
    Actual type: Session Settings s IO Text -> IO Text
  In the first argument of ‘printAccountCount’, namely ‘dbHandle’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: printAccountCount dbHandle
```

**Updated Error**

After some help below - I got to a new error:

```
src/Main.hs:29:24:
    Couldn't match type ‘r0’ with ‘a’
      because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      a type expected by the context: Session Settings s IO a -> IO a
      at src/Main.hs:29:7-31
    Expected type: Session Settings s IO a -> IO a
      Actual type: Session Settings s IO r0 -> IO r0
    Relevant bindings include
      dbHandle :: Session Settings s IO r0 -> IO r0
        (bound at src/Main.hs:27:5)
    In the first argument of ‘printAHsqlString’, namely ‘dbHandle’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: printAHsqlString dbHandle
```

How do I let that type variable remain flexible between calls?

Full (updated) Code: https://gist.github.com/cschneid/4174addefb254a517f35

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Since [version 0.6.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasql-0.6.0) there no longer is any `sessionUnlifter` fuss. Pool is directly exposed and you can execute `Session` on it as many times as you want without any performance penalty.

Comment: This gets me a new error - which is confusing.  I explicitly tell it that result is an Int when I go to print it: 

 `Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
  from the context (MonadBase IO m)`

Full Error is at https://gist.github.com/cschneid/4174addefb254a517f35 in the comment.

Comment: I'm getting closer - new errors.  I tried adding a `forall s a.` here, but that didn't help.   `Couldn't match type ‘r0’ with ‘a’
      because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope`  Full error is in the Gist.

Comment: @cschneid I managed to reproduce your issue. It seems to identify a problem in Hasql's API. Unfortunately I don't have any time to deal with this today. I'll be working on a solution in the coming days and will post back here. In the mean time you can downgrade to a version 0.2.3, where `Session` is an alias to `ReaderT`, which should not bring you troubles of this kind.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking your time to look at this - is there a github issue around this so I can track it?

Comment: No, there's no issue yet. I'll post back here any way, so you'll be informed.

Comment: For anybody following along at home - this issue covers this: https://github.com/nikita-volkov/hasql/issues/22